# Is the debugger attached?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I would like to know, whether I'm currently debugging my javascript code?

**Background:** (Why I need to know)

I have created a page, that spawns a `Worker`.

When I run this page and press `F12` to debug, I set a breakpoint in the `Worker`. This breakpoint will then get hit when I press my button to run the Worker (so far all good).

Now to prevent that the `Worker` runs forever I have created a simple timer in the main page, that terminates the `Worker` after 2 seconds, like this:

```
    timer = setTimeout(function ()
    {
        worker.terminate();
        worker = NewWorker();
    }, 2000);
```

**Now the problem: When the breakpoint is hit in Worker, the timer fires 2 seconds later** (since the main page thread is still running independantly) and terminates the `Worker`. So I can't debug the `Worker`.

My plan is to simply disable (or not start) the timer, when I'm debugging.

**So, Is there a way to know, if a debugger is attached?**

**Update:**

My current workaround is to simply comment out the timer code, when I want to debug the `Worker`, but I would like to do a test.

**Update2:**

May be a debugger is always attached in the browser, but it's only `active` when it's **visible**. Breakpoints are only hit when you have the debugger window open.

**So, is there a way to test that?**

Comment: I'd use a bundler e.g. webpack, and do a development build without and a production build with the timeout.

Comment: Isn't there always a debugger attached in a browser?

Comment: Alternatively use a global variable e.g. `var debug = false` then run `debug = true` in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems, there's no answer to this question.

Ideally I would want the browser to **break all threads** when one thread hit a breakpoint (Visual Studio can do this, but not in javascript).

May be one day browsers will support this.

**Update:**

Now Visual Studio supports debugging `Worker`. It's still an experimental feature. You enable it using the weirdly named option in '`Options`', '`Debugger`':

```
Enable using the multi-target Javascript debugger for debugging Javascript in applicable targets (requires debugging restart)
```

To debug a Worker, start debugging your page, then Visual Studio `Solution Explorer` will show show the `Worker.js` file. double-click and breakpoints.

However it has not really solved the problem with timers in the main thread firing when you hit a breakpoint in a `Worker`.