# How to determine whether the WebView2 DevTools are currently open?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webview2

The DevTools that come with WebView2 can either be opened by the user e.g. by pressing the <kbd>F12</kbd> key, and they also can be [opened programatically from code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64981617/107625).

What I do not know is how to determine whether the DevTools are currently being opened.

I want to store the state (opened/closed) upon the exit of my WPF application so that I can show them automatically upon the next start of my WPF application.

##### My question

How to get the current showing/not showing state of the WebView2 Developer Tools?

---

##### Update 1

I found a dirty hack because of the fact that the window title of the DevTools looks like this:

> DevTools - localhost:38472/my/url

Whereas `localhost:38472/my/url` is the currently loaded URL of the WebView2.

So I'm doing the following.

With the help of [this SO answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7268375/107625) I was able to create this method:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> GetAllDesktopMainWindowTitles()
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/7268375/107625

    var processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (var process in processlist)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
        {
            yield return process.MainWindowTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

I then can use it like this:

```cs
public static bool AreDevToolsOpen(this WebView2? webView)
{
    var url = webView?.Source?.ToString();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) return false;

    url = url.Replace(@"https://", string.Empty).Replace(@"http://", string.Empty);

    var titles = GetAllDesktopMainWindowTitles().ToList();

    var devToolsOpen = titles.Any(t => t.Contains(@"DevTools") && t.Contains(url));

    return devToolsOpen;
}
```

While this is a total hack, it seems to work good enough for now.

Still, I'm looking for a better way to do it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61549409/is-the-debugger-attached

Comment: Why do you want to know this? There is a way to know it is not open with AreDevToolsEnabled Property. Then once you have set this it will only be open if you open it.

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2settings.aredevtoolsenabled?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1343.22) says: "**Determines whether the user is able to use the context menu or keyboard shortcuts to open the DevTools window.**" How is this related to my question?